# Flat file data validation

Tags: validation, csv, etl, flat-file

I am supposed to load some data that is received in flat files (csv). The problem is that the supplier is generating a lot of junk data. 
before starting to develop anything new on my own, I would like to ask if there is something that could automate this process.

I have found an open source tool called [flat file checker](http://www.flat-file.net/), It can accept a bunch of various validation rules including regex, but the problem is that it does not work. It is exactly what I need, but it is not validating.

Does anyone have any suggestion for something like this, but actually works

Comment: Recommendations are strictly off-topic on SO.

Comment: Since you include tag *etl*: Are you starting from scratch or are you already bound to an ETL framework?

Comment: at a later point of the process, ... I am. but this is supossed to get validated before it gets in contact to any other data storages with a valid integrity and validated data. Kind of, ... preprocessing validation

Comment: Perl, Python, pick one, learn one, it's the most flexible way to take a file and validate to your heart's content.

Comment: Which version of flat file checker did you try? what exactly does not work?

Comment: absolutely nothing. in the UI you can click anything, but the processing is not working. tried it also with the command line tool. nothing